# Making Access toolbar visible

Tags: ms-access, toolbar

I have an Access 2000 application that a client wants updated to Office 365. The old db has a toolbar that I’d like to use but it appears under “Add-Ins” on the main ribbon. The toolbar works just fine but it’s very awkward and unprofessional to have the user select it from the add-Ins menu. How do it make visible when the db is opened?

Comment: Might not be possible. According to MS docs, showing up on Add-Ins tab is expected behavior. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-custom-toolbars-and-startup-settings-from-earlier-versions-of-access-eeea8c31-c2fb-4f36-81a7-7886e168a2c8

Answer (score 0):

Is this still a mdb, or was it converted to accDB (or accDE)?

How big/extensive is the add-in menu? (extensive, or just a few options???).
If just a few options, then you could create a custom ribbon.

A HUGE but BEYOND huge tip? - don't use ribbon call backs. I can expand on this suggestion. But as a general rule the SAME command for the menu can be created and used for the ribbon - and without a call back.

So, right now, about your only option would be to:

Use an access 2000, or 2003 runtime (if you have a copy).

Or consider building a custom ribbon. I mean, a2000? That is 22 years ago.

Comment: Yea, it’s old. But a former Clint remembered it and will pay me well to revive it. It’s now a accdb to be delivered as accde. It’s a pretty extensive menu with sub menus and a few sub-sub menus. I guess I’ll have to make a custom ribbon. Did I mention that I’ve always hated the ribbon? A friend who is a Microsoft employee officially apologized to me for the ribbon (over a beer).